# gRPC for C++ on Windows, dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

This is going to be a little long of an introduction, but I think it i neccessary for you to understand what I've already tried.

I am currently trying to set up a gRPC Client with C++, after i already set up a Server and Client in Python with no problem. However for C++ the building of gRPC is just evil. With the resources form the offivial git repository I was able to build gRPC (or so i thought) but when I then tried to build my project with Cmake i got an error that the gRPCTargets.cmake is missing. Tracing this back I found that I had to build gRPC itself with all the dependencies as packages instead of submodules. So I started by downloading C-Ares and building it. No Problem here. Next I tried reconfiguring gRPC with the new c-ares directory variable set and type package set. Now i encountered a Problem that the in c-ares-config.cmake an include directory is specified which does not exist at all.

```
get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)

macro(set_and_check _var _file)
  set(${_var} "${_file}")
  if(NOT EXISTS "${_file}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "File or directory ${_file} referenced by variable ${_var} does not exist !")
  endif()
endmacro()

set_and_check(c-ares_INCLUDE_DIR "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/include")

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/c-ares-targets.cmake")
```

For me the Path with /../../../ doesn't make any sense but since it's automatically generated and I am pretty much a noob using Cmake I cannot say what would be correct there. All i know is that there is no folder named include inside any of the c-ares folders. I tried removing the set_and_check(...) line, which removes the error, but now I am asked for a c-ares-targets.cmake which cannot be found.

I am pretty much stuck here. I would highly appreciate any help or ideas fixing this.

Maybe there is an option of getting a precompiled gRPC-resource for C++ on windows, but was unable to find any sources.

Comment: "I found that I had to build gRPC itself with all the dependencies" - Moreover, you need to **install** gRPC (but possibly into the custom *install prefix*). "For me the Path with /../../../ doesn't make any sense" - This is how *install prefix* (`PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR`) is compute. But again, this works only when gRPC is *installed*.

Comment: Yes, please mention if you installed gRPC after building it. Thanks!